# Where is a good place to ask questions about Drupal AND Drupal modules?

Tags: discussion

Can anybody recommend a site for questions/ help with Drupal and Drupal modules? Something like Drupal Answers? I'm aware of the official Drupal forum, but it's like an echo chamber, unfortunately.

I'm reaching the end of my tether with this problem and the problems I'm having with Drupal, so any recommendations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can ask *questions* here. Your other post was not a question, that was a bug report. And bug reports need to be submitted to the issue queue of that module so that they can be fixed.

Comment: maybe you're not aware of the difference between the Drupal forums and the module issue queues, and the difference between a question and a bug report. Questions can be asked in Drupal Answers, bug reports should be filed in the module's issue queue, the Drupal forums should be avoided unless you particularly like trolls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking questions about Drupal on *Drupal Answers* is perfectly fine, as the purpose of the site is to answer questions about Drupal.

As any Stack Exchange site, there are some rules about which questions suit on *Drupal Answers*, which must be followed to avoid a question is closed as off-topic. As the site is still in beta, the FAQ doesn't help a lot to understand which questions are on-topic, but as general rule, questions about bug reports are not questions you should ask on drupal.SE for two reasons:

- The right place to report issue reports is drupal.org; if you would like to know how to workaround the bug, the answer you could get is to wait for the next release of the module.
- A question about bugs is relevant until a bug is resolved; after the bug is resolved, nobody  would be interested to the question and its answers.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answers. I was also told about Stack Overflow, which looks like a good place for broader Drupal and Drupal module questions.

Comment: @James Stack Overflow doesn't permit broader Drupal questions, except in the case the question is not focused on Drupal.

Comment: Which site is "***still in beta***"? Maybe you want to rework that part of your answer?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I am talking of _Drupal Answers_, which was still in beta phase at the time the question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

I think https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ would be the most trusted for Drupal developers and administrators among other Drupal community platforms. For a newbie like me, I found it to be the best for my issues.

Answer (score 3):

These days (6 years after this question was asked ...) there is also the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site, which also has a [dedicated ***Drupal*** tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal), with an excerpt that starts with "*For software (modules etc.) that needs to work with Drupal*".

In my experience it is a perfect fit for questions like "***`Is there a contributed Drupal module to do so and so?`***" (a kind of question that appears to ***NOT*** comply with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (oeps: rules) of the [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) site).

For some samples of such questions on that site, have a look at [some of these posts on that site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[drupal]) (using the **Drupal** tag).